# localStorage not working when I restart the app - phonegap iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am trying to cache JSON data on the local storage so I can use the data when there is no internet connection.

It works fine but when I restart the app I think the localstorage cleared.

Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    
    document.addEventListener("offline", function() {
    alert("No internet connection");


    $.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo')), function(key, val) {
    if(!(val.php)){val.php=0;}
$('ul.get-mertchant').append('<li> <a href="azkadenya.html?id=' + val.nid + '&nop='+ val.php +'" class="li-link"><div class="circle-img"><img src="'+ val.logo + '" /></div><div class="merchant-info"><h1>'+ val.node_title +'</h1><p>You Have '+ val.php +' Binggz</p></div><div class="more-icon"></div></a> </li>');
}); 
    
}, false);
    $.getJSON('mywebsite/views/services_merchant_mobile', function(data) {
        localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify(data));
        
var items = [];
$.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo')), function(key, val) {
    if(!(val.php)){val.php=0;}
$('ul.get-mertchant').append('<li> <a href="azkadenya.html?id=' + val.nid + '&nop='+ val.php +'" class="li-link"><div class="circle-img"><img src="'+ val.logo + '" /></div><div class="merchant-info"><h1>'+ val.node_title +'</h1><p>You Have '+ val.php +' Binggz</p></div><div class="more-icon"></div></a> </li>');
});

})
}
```

Comment: what version of phonegap are you using?

Comment: @JasonFreitas I am using cordova 2.3.0

Comment: @JasonFreitas did u find out what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What size has the json data you stringify? Localstorage has limitiation to the size of the values so this may be a problem.

Have you got any logs in the xcode console?

I see that you call getJSON every time the device is ready. If you want to refresh this data every time the application start maybe the better idea is to cache the result from the json call in the global javascript object instead of stringify and parse json many times.

A small tip for you. Try to not to use $.append() function in this way. It's very expensive especially on Mobiles.
You can either concatenate the list items and than call append() function only once or you can use some template engine like jquery template or handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from IOS 5.1 Apple decided to make local storage a temp area. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923296/localstorage-cleared-after-restarting-the-application-on-phonegap-ios#answer-16045158).