# Localstorage cleared after restarting the application on phonegap IOS?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to cache JSON data on in localstorage to load it when there is no internet connection. It is working fine but when I restart the app I think the localstorage cleared

Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {

    document.addEventListener("offline", function() {
    alert("No internet connection");


    $.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo')), function(key, val) {
    if(!(val.php)){val.php=0;}
$('ul.get-mertchant').append('<li> <a href="azkadenya.html?id=' + val.nid + '&nop='+ val.php +'" class="li-link"><div class="circle-img"><img src="'+ val.logo + '" /></div><div class="merchant-info"><h1>'+ val.node_title +'</h1><p>You Have '+ val.php +' Binggz</p></div><div class="more-icon"></div></a> </li>');
}); 

}, false);
    $.getJSON('mywebsite/views/services_merchant_mobile', function(data) {
        localStorage.setItem('foo', JSON.stringify(data));

var items = [];
$.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('foo')), function(key, val) {
    if(!(val.php)){val.php=0;}
$('ul.get-mertchant').append('<li> <a href="azkadenya.html?id=' + val.nid + '&nop='+ val.php +'" class="li-link"><div class="circle-img"><img src="'+ val.logo + '" /></div><div class="merchant-info"><h1>'+ val.node_title +'</h1><p>You Have '+ val.php +' Binggz</p></div><div class="more-icon"></div></a> </li>');
});

})
}
```

what is wrong??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting from IOS 5.1 Apple decided to make local storage a temp area. If you need persistent storage on iOS 5.1, use PhoneGap's File API. Here are a couple links to learn about the issue.

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegapbuild_localstorage_on_ios_5_1

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Apple discurages you from using local storage as well.
[iOS PhoneGap app rejected because of the use of localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282032/ios-phonegap-app-rejected-because-of-the-use-of-localstorage)

Comment: The follow-up on that first link (community post on localstorage_on_ios_5_1) says the issue was resolved in PhoneGap 1.6.

The cordova_storage docs linked provide no indication that localStorage is not persistent.

The "app rejected" link is about (misplaced) concerns of app data being backed up to iCloud, not problems with it being persistent across app restarts.

I have some questions remaining about "is localStorage saved in a 'cache' location or a 'data' location" and "when does iOS remove things from cache," but I don't see evidence that localStorage is typically lost on app restart.

Comment: The very same problem happens with Android when using Cordova 6.1.1.

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html
`localStorage` is listed as an option to store persistent data. Your sources are outdated/dead. Is there still a situaton where localStorage might get deleted?