# Phonegap Sqlite, WebStorage, LocalStorage. Which one?

Tags: cordova

I am investigating converting a mysql database over into a phonegap app.

Now with HTML5 there is a specification for Web Storage (Is it commonly called local storage?)
This is what I believe Phonegap uses via it's storage method/api. Which would be key value string pairs correct?

But I am reading up on this tutorial and it keeps mentioning Phonegap and Sqlite as a built in  api. It is using proper SQL syntax.

Which is used natively?

Sorry if this is very confusing to read, it is very confusing for me to get my head round.

Comment: did you get answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

As per phonegap documentation:

> This API is based on the W3C Web SQL Database Specification and W3C
>   Web Storage API Specification. Some devices already provide an
>   implementation of this spec. For those devices, the built-in support
>   is used instead of replacing it with Cordova's implementation. For
>   devices that don't have storage support, Cordova's implementation
>   should be compatible with the W3C specification.

Phonegap allows hooks so that you can access the various storage options on the device.
As far I understand, the term localstorage object is an HTML feature where a web browser stores information and this is a bad option for storing data as I have seen this gets cleared every time you launch your application again.

On the other hand if you use the database object it is saved even after you launch the application again.

Local Storage
http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Phonegap
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

Comment: Don't confuse people if you haven't used that. Localstorage is NOT being cleared unless you tell it to. Sessionstorage lasts for the time app is running. And I actually had problems with making sqlite work at all with phonegap (I abandoned that in the end). Localstorage is good option for passing data through views and to keep some simple data.

Comment: @m4rt: I have used both local storage and SQLite for my phonegap application.  Please see this link for local storage clearing issue of phonegap: : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923296/localstorage-cleared-after-restarting-the-application-on-phonegap-ios

Comment: Interesting, although I didn't have any problems with localstorage so far (also on iphone 3 and ipad), I should look into that also then.

Comment: I don't know if they rolled it back, but in iOS 7.1 that doesn't happens at all, just to update the thread