# Proper way to store variables between views in Ionic Framework (Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have following problem: in my app based on Ionic Framework I have something like authentication: I log in and after that store token in a service.

But what is a proper way to store variables? I could use services, localStorage, (something else)?

For example, after login I want to show a list and depending on choice (on an id from a list) show something in details tab, but still have an ability to move for example to account tab, or other tab and still have an information on selected choice (like, clicking on details tab still would show previously selected item).

So how for example store such a variable?

I hope I didn't mess the explanation of my problem too much.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to store variables for the current session only or you want to keep the values even if the app is stopped??

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For now I would need to store variables only when app is alive, not after restart.

Comment: You should check the ionic forums before posting a question here; this question has been asked am answered multiple times there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage`. It's pretty good for this kind of little things.

```
localStorage.setItem("storage_name","something");
var another_variable=localStorage.getItem("storage_name");
```

And if you need the values even after restarting the app, then you will need something like `webSql`, specially for iOS

Comment: localStorage is persistent even if you close the app.

Comment: AFAIK not in iOS. iOS consider localStorage as temporary @AndrewMcGivery

Comment: localStorage, by definition, is persistent, and I have tested this in apps that I have created. I just tested it now on a device.  sessionStorage, is not persistent, but localStorage is.

Comment: I have read somewhere that iOS treat localStorage as temporary. It'll wipe out the localStorage if it needs that memory. @AndrewMcGivery

Comment: >Starting from IOS 5.1 Apple decided to make local storage a temp area.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923296/localstorage-cleared-after-restarting-the-application-on-phonegap-ios
@AndrewMcGivery

Comment: I stand corrected, however if you read this thread, PhoneGap 3.0 fixes this issue, so it works as expected. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664392/phonegap-ios-5-1-and-localstorage